# htaccess redirection for html files and other links

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I was in the need of migrating my site to a subfolder, it is a php script, its links are like this :

aff_link.php?id=812 (number changes at the end)
and html files like
gifts.html
rss_feeds.html
and others ending in .html

I need to redirect those two kind of links to a subfolder called "old"

any advice on this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ive tried this : RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://domain.com/old$1.html but it repeats the diretory "old" several times like http://domain.com/old/old/old/old/old/rss_feeds.html

Comment: I manage to redirect the .html files one by one using a plugin, but now my problem is with this links aff_link.php?id=812

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)q=id=\d+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^aff_link\.php$ /old/$0 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```